# Are private attributes hidden by default by .perl and .gist

Tags: oop, raku

That seems to be the case:

```
class Foo { has $!bar }; say Foo.new( :3bar ).perl # OUTPUT: «Foo.new␤»
```

Documentation says [it's implementation dependent](https://docs.raku.org/routine/perl), but I wonder if this actually makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.perl` output is correct.  `Foo.new( :3bar )` does **not** do what you think.  If you add a `method bar() { $!bar }`, you'll notice that the private attribute `$!bar` did **not** get set:

```
class Foo {
    has $!bar;
    method bar() { $!bar }
}
say Foo.new( :3bar ).bar;   # (Any)
say Foo.new( :3bar ).perl;  # Foo.new
```

The named parameter `:3bar` (aka `bar => 3`) is silently ignored, because there is **no public** attribute with the name `bar`.

If you want it to complain about this situation, then maybe https://modules.raku.org/dist/StrictNamedArguments is something for you.

Comment: the link is broken - it needs to point to either https://modules.perl6.org/dist/StrictNamedArguments:github:Claudio%20Ramirez (which redirects to github) or https://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=StrictNamedArguments